# Query not showing results

Tags: php

I am doing this query.  It doesn't show me the result which in $products.

code:

```
$sql = "SELECT s*
     FROM Client_agent_approvals caa
     INNER JOIN Subscriptions s ON s.client_id = caa.client_id
     WHERE caa.agent_id = '$id'
     AND s.agent_id <> '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

if ($result == "") {
    echo "";
}
echo "";


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rows == 0) {
    print("");
} elseif ($rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $product = $row['product'];

        print("Products they have are: $product");
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time you might want to more properly indent your code. It's more convenient when reading it. (Also a general tip for any coding you do.)

Answer (score 1):

You have `s*`. I think you mean `s.*`. You should also use do... while for query iteration:

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

 if(!$row) 
 {
     print('no rows');// a more useful message
 }
 else
 {
    do {

        $product = $row['product'];

         print("Products they have are: $product");
     }
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));

 }
```

`mysql_num_rows` actually counts all of the values returned, this does not. You can almost say that it is doing twice the work for the same result.

Of course, all of this assumes that there were one or more rows returned to begin with. Can you confirm that you should be getting something by running this in MySQL directly?

Comment: yeah i am just getting the Products are part but not the desired result $product.  Let me fix it using your solution.

Comment: used your suggestion and it says "no rows" but there are entries that should be returning...

Comment: shouldn't printing "no rows" happen if ( ! $row) ?

Comment: @Codercake Yep. Bug in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you have edited your code after the comment that was just posted, that was not what was meant by "indentation". you can indent the statements inside loop's and if's to make it more readable.

try using print_r on $rows and $row before doing anything with them. it may help you see what is going on with those variables.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php